# What does "\!\!" mean?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

For example, in the mathematical notation of a quotient space given an equivalence relation `\sim`, the rendering of `X/\sim` is different from `X/\!\!\sim`. In the former, there is a gap between the slash and the `\sim`, whereas in the latter, there is no such gap. I couldn't find meaningful entries on Google.

Comment: `\!` in mathmode is a small backspace.  Two of them are double that.

Comment: Thanks Steven. Now "backspace in math mode" gives me good results on Google. Just needed to know the right keywords.

Comment: It's wrong usage, anyway: if you want no space between the slash and the `\sim`, type `X/{\sim}`. The reason is that `\sim` is a relation symbol, while `/` is an ordinary one, so TeX inserts a thick space between them. With `{\sim}` the symbol is turned into an ordinary one, and TeX inserts no space.

Comment: @egreg: Yeah your method is more elegant. I just was annoyed by that extra space and inspected the source of a Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) to see how they do it. They use "\!\!".

Comment: @AhmedNassar Somebody writes x/~ in order to denote the equivalence class of x. Try `$X/\!\!\sim=\{x/\!\!\sim\mid x\in X\}$` and `$X/{\sim}=\{x/{\sim}\mid x\in X\}$` and see the difference. Here's the [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7FFq3.png) So it's not only more elegant: it's right as opposed to wrong. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg  These seem to be subtle things that are great to know.  I know a few but often wonder what other *tricks* I'm missing.  It seems it would be nice if there were some kind of brief reference for such things.  Is there such a reference?

Comment: @A.Ellett The TeXbook or TeX by Topic. If you can read Italian, http://www.guitex.org/home/images/ArsTeXnica/AT008/Simboli%20matematici%20in%20TEX%20e%20LATEX.pdf

Comment: @egreg While I do not read Italian, there's enough context in your pdf link to figure out what they're talking about.  I found the material in TeX by Topic, but it would be hard to find if you only wanted to know how to suppress the spacing.  The link I find more helpful.